# Linter flake8 cannot find flake8, even though executablePath is specified

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

I have recently installed flake8 and linter-flake8 and I am trying to use it in Atom. It did not get installed on PATH so I have specified the executable path in the settings of linter-flake8 package on atom using:

```
'linter-flake8':
  'executablePath': 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages'
```

but still getting the error:"[Linter] Error running Flake8". Why isn't it finding flake8?

Comment: I recently had this problem. In my case, I'd installed the linter-flake8 plugin and its dependencies in Atom, but hadn't installed flake8 itself with `pip install flake8`. After I did that, and restarted Atom, it worked

Answer (score 1):

According to the [README](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8#settings), you need to provide the path to the executable, not the containing directory.

**Example:**

```coffee
'linter-flake8':
  'executablePath': 'c:\users\user\appdata\...\site-packages\flake8.exe'
```

Comment: I set it that way, and nothing, I am still getting the same error